# integration with ExactTarget using Fuelsdk-Ruby

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, fuel-sdk, ruby

Intergration with ExactTarget using fuelsdk, ruby 1.9.3. 
The integration works as well but we face with responses slowness.
each response takes more than 10 seconds! Is this to be expected?

Comment: I would suggest adding an issue to the github repo.

Comment: Using the FuelSDK for Ruby, I am able to see sub-second respond times.  If you are instantiating a new Client class for each request, there is a bit of overhead with that as it handles authentication so it is best to maintain a single Client object as long as possible. Even with that, it should not be taking 10 seconds.